# How to validate a subdomain name by widecard nginx server

Tags: nginx

I allowed to my dns provider to put any subdomain and my nginx default.conf attached below. I want to allow some listed subdomains at runtime.

- Case1: test.example.com and best.example.com both are allowed from DNS but i want to allow only test.example.com so how to match a subdomain name from a list of valid subdomains.
- Case2: These valid subdomains will maintain on some external http api.
- Case3: Mai i execute some external python or c code for validate this.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    if($1 != 'test') {
           rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 redirect;
    }
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
          #rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 redirect;
    }
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Put each separate name you want to allow in server_name in the proper server configuration and create a separate server that acts as default_server which denies access to anything.
2. Use the map module of nginx and return an error code if your name is not in the list. The map module also supports wildcards.

Comment: Hey Florin,
That was really helpful. Look at mine new conf file it is working fine now.

map $http_host $new {
        include /var/www/html/blognginx.map;
#       'www.myassignmentpro.com' '1';
#       'dev.myassignmentpro.com' '1';
}

server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        location / {
                if ($new != '1') {
                        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.myassignmentpro.com$1 redirect;
                }
        }
}

Comment: One more small issue i am facing in this that is i don't want to restart nginx after adding some records in map file is it possible?

Comment: You can probably reload it.